# Image does not load in webpage

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jpeg

I have created a webpage with twitter bootstrap css, and have an image link. Image attached. However, this image does not load. All other images load.

Can someone tell me the problem

Code is as follows:

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
                    <img class="img-responsive img-border-left" src="../img/aircheck.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
```

The link to image is www.airtec-intl.com/img/aircheck.jpg.

Comment: The url given returns 403 forbidden - in html format, not as an image.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure of the relative path?
Try this out:

```
<img class="img-responsive img-border-left" src="img/aircheck.jpg" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever browse the url?

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /img/aircheck.jpg on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

How can you expect this url to load?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, all other images are accessible only this one is forbidden. I have used exactly the same method to upload the image to the server as the other images. do i need to set any permissions while uploading an image to make it accessible

Comment: Depending on your operating system and the ftp(?) client the original permissions are sent to the server or not. But you will have to try it yourself. Also, it depends on the server configuration what permissions are required. On a linux server, if `u+r` is not enough, then use `g+r`